# SSRS Security add many users

Tags: reporting-services, roles, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a list of over 300 users I want to add to SSRS Security as "Browsers".  I was wondering, is there a way to do this programmatically and not by doing New Role Assignment for each and every user?

Comment: How will your users be viewing your reports? Do the users already have user accounts on the network? Is it required that each user be given a unique username/password? Is there any middle-ware applications involved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming these users have an Active Directory profile:

1. Create a AD group "SSRSBrowsers".
2. Add the 300 to that group (preferably before the Persians arrive).
3. Create an SSRS browse-only security entry for DOMAIN\SSRSBrowsers.
4. Profit.

Comment: Agreed - do NOT try and add 300 individual user accounts to a folder in Report Manager, you will end up in a world of admin pain when they start leaving etc. Active Directory groups are definitely the way forward.

Comment: also +1 for mentioning the Persians :)

Comment: Also agreeing here.  Even though you absolutely *could* automate inserting 300 individual users, then you're stuck *maintaining* 300 individual users.  Go for a group.

Comment: Should ahve marked as answer a while ago.  And +1 million for the Persians.