# Security on report server URL for SSRS

Tags: security, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which takes DEPARTMENT_ID as parameter. Users can only see report of their own department but problem is anyone can access the below URL and view other department's report.

```
http://<server>/Reports
```

OR

```
http://<server>/ReportServer?/<FolderName>/Report&DEPARTMENT_ID=5
```

Is there a way to make these URLs secure so only authorized users can access it? Or this option is not available in SSRS and I have to block access through firewall or something? Like disallowing access to this URL from all IPs and only allow my web server IP to access it and then I make a page in ASP.Net in which I show this report using Report Viewer?

Comment: Are you using AD to control report access currently?

Comment: No. Currently anyone can access it.

Comment: In that case, I would create appropriate AD groups and add the employees to them, then map the groups to permission groups in SSRS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671403/ssrs-security-add-many-users/22672289#22672289.  Might as well leverage the built-in security model.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem because every one needs to have access to that report anyway. It's just that if you belong to Deparment A then that report should only show report of Department A. It takes Department ID as parameter which anyone can change.

Comment: Use the User!UserID in the report to identify the windows user running the report and maintain a table of users departments. Use this table to force the data to be filtered by department when the user runs it.