# Reporting service "NO ACCESS!"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Ok so I work in a company where everyone logs in the reporting services with their AD (Active Directory) account and i have given each and everyone different access to different folders.

One day everyone is getting the same error after I enabled remote errors:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
 Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
 NO ACCESS!

This happens when they click "View Report" so they can log in and browse the reports but not generate them.

Also i have an administrator account which strangely can generate the reports without any problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Is it a embedded or a shared datasource ? If shared, have you changed the policy of the datasource of the report? You could create another datasource and point a report to this datasource and see if it executes successfully.

Comment: 1. What account is the report server using to access the data on the SQL server? 2. Did you actually assign individual users to reports?  You should do this with AD Groups to make maintenance easier.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671403/ssrs-security-add-many-users/22672289#22672289.

Comment: Found it thank you guys, it was authentication inside the stored procedure -_-